# Why Lua works that way and how to fix floating numbers problem?

Tags: lua

That is my code:

```
a=20.4*100
print(a,math.floor(a),math.floor(2040))
```

Result in console:

```
2040    2039    2040
```

If a==2040 then why when I do `math.floor` with that number, its decreasing?
How can I write mathematical functions with better precisions then that strange behavior?

Comment: This is the most frequent question on SO :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I discovered that strange behavior occurs in JavaScript too

Comment: How can I fix this in lua?

Comment: here is how math.floor is defined: http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lmathlib.c.html#math_floor

Comment: `a` doesn't equal `2040`. “When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.”

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: computers don't have infinite memory, so they can only use so many bits to store a number. If the number has too many decimals, they will get cut off somewhere, and it just so happens that 0.4 (two fifth) in binary representation has more decimals than it cans save; so after cutting them off, you're left with 0.399999something, which `print` is smart enough to print as 0.4, but if you `floor()` it, it gets rounded down without mercy, leading to the results you see.

Also please note that you could have just googled this; it's one of the most common questions in programming ;)

---

As an example, try this:

```lua
string.format("%f",     20.4*100)
--> 2040.000000
string.format("%0.20f", 20.4*100)
--> 2039.99999999999977262632
```